# Is there a way I can have my bot log every time a user sends a message and every time they join vc? Would make keeping track of active members easier

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, discord, discord.js

We currently use spreadsheets to keep track of activity and have to go through discord and see when they sent a message and such. Would be a lot easier if a bot was able to do this.

[image]

I want the bot to log every time a specific user sends a message and/or joins a voice channel. Whether it's sending a message in a channel saying that a member send something or just anything at all to keep track

I don't know much about code so if you could help that would be amazing. I tried looking it up but I don't know how to word the search and I didn't get anything helpful to someone new to code.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do with the collected information, however below is an example on how you could collect the data.

Firstly, you need to create a bot using the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Secondly, you need to install required packages (ensure that you have node.js installed):

```bash
npm i --save discord.js
```

Here is an example of the code:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  fetchAllMembers: true,
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
  ]
});

// Listen for new messages
client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  // Ignore bot messages
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // Get the current date and time
  let date = new Date().toString();
  // Log the event to the console
  console.log(`${message.author.username} has sent a message at ${date}`);
});

client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function(oldState, newState) {
  // Get the date and time of the event
  let date = new Date().toString();

  // Collect information
});

// Login
client.login("your-token here");
```

Comment: Basically, we use google sheets to keep track of the last time a member send a message or joined a vc to keep track of their activity. Its a big server so its a lot to do manually. I was just wondering if there is a way to connect sheets to my discord bot and use a members Discord ID or something to automatically log (update the date as seen in the image above) everytime they send a message or join vc in a certain category/channel in my server

Comment: @Angalie There are several [google sheets nom packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=google%20sheets). You will have to do some research in which one works best for your needs and integrate it with the code provided above.